# Что делает ключевое слова «yield»?

Tags: python, итераторы, генераторы, yield

Для чего нужен и как использовать ключевое слово `yield`?

Например, я пытаюсь понять этот код<sub>1</sub>:

```
def _get_child_candidates(self, distance, min_dist, max_dist):
    if self._leftchild and distance - max_dist < self._median:
        yield self._leftchild
    if self._rightchild and distance + max_dist >= self._median:
        yield self._rightchild
```

это вызывается здесь:

```
result, candidates = [], [self]
while candidates:
    node = candidates.pop()
    distance = node._get_dist(obj)
    if distance <= max_dist and distance >= min_dist:
        result.extend(node._values)
    candidates.extend(node._get_child_candidates(distance, min_dist, max_dist))
return result
```

Что происходит при вызове метода `_get_child_candidates`? Возвращается список? Один элемент? Это Вызывается снова? Когда прекратятся последующие Вызовы?

---

1. Этот фрагмент кода написал Jochen Schulz (jrschulz), который создал отличную библиотеку для метрических пространств. ссылка на полный источник: Модуль [mspace](http://well-adjusted.de/%7Ejrschulz/mspace/)

<sub>Перевод вопроса [What does the "yield" keyword do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do) от участника [Alex. S.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18300/alex-s)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do

Comment: Перед ассоциацией было бы  не лишне проверить на дублиикаты. Но всё равно, топик будет полезен (++).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы понять, что делает `yield`, вы должны понять, что такое *генераторы*. И прежде чем вы сможете понять генераторы, вы должны понять что такое *итераторы*

## Итераторы

Когда вы создаете список, вы можете читать его элементы один за другим. Чтение его элементов по одному называется итерацией:

```
>>> mylist = [1, 2, 3]
>>> for i in mylist:
...    print(i)
1
2
3
```

`mylist` - *итерируем*. Когда вы используете [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) вы создаете список и, итерируете по нему:

```
>>> mylist = [x*x for x in range(3)]
>>> for i in mylist:
...    print(i)
0
1
4
```

Все, что вы можете использовать `for ... in ...`, является итерируемым: списки, строки, файлы...

Итерируемые объекты удобны, потому что вы можете читать их сколько угодно, но вы храните все значения в памяти, но это не удобно когда у вас много значений.

## Генераторы

Генераторы - это итератор, который можно **проитерировать только один раз**.
Генераторы не хранят все значения в памяти, они **генерируют значения на лету**:

```
>>> mygenerator = (x*x for x in range(3))
>>> for i in mygenerator:
...    print(i)
0
1
4
```

Это то же самое, за исключением того, что вы использовали `()` вместо `[]`. НО, вы **не можете** выполнить `for i in mygenerator` второй раз, поскольку генератор можно использовать только один раз: он вычисляют `0`, затем забывают об этом и вычисляют `1` и забывает 2 об этом, и т.д.

## yield

Ключевое слово `yield` используется как `return`, за исключением того, что функция вернет генератор.

```
>>> def createGenerator():
...    mylist = range(3)
...    for i in mylist:
...        yield i*i
...
>>> mygenerator = createGenerator() # создаётся генератор
>>> print(mygenerator) # mygenerator - это объект!
<generator object createGenerator at 0xb7555c34>
>>> for i in mygenerator:
...     print(i)
0
1
4
```

Здесь это бесполезный пример, но это удобно, когда вы знаете, что ваша функция вернет огромный набор значений, которые вам нужно будет прочитать только один раз.

Чтобы освоить `yield`, вы должны понимать, что **при вызове функции код, написанный в теле функции, не выполняется**. Функция возвращает только объект генератора, это немного сложно :-)

Затем ваш код будет продолжаться с того места, где он остановился, каждый раз, когда `for` использует генератор.

Теперь самое сложное:

В первый раз, когда `for` вызывает объект-генератор, созданный из вашей функции, он запускает код в вашей функции с самого начала до тех пор, пока не достигнет `yield`, после чего он вернет первое значение цикла. Затем каждый последующий вызов будет запускать другую итерацию цикла, который вы написали в функции, и возвращать следующее значение. Это будет продолжаться до тех пор, пока генератор не будет считаться пустым, что происходит, когда функция выполняется без достижения `yield`. Это может быть из-за того, что цикл подошел к концу, или из-за того, что условие `if/else` больше не выполнилось.

---

### Объяснение вашего кода

генератор:

```
# Здесь вы создаете метод объекта `node`
# который вернет генератор

def _get_child_candidates(self, distance, min_dist, max_dist):


     # Вот код, который будет вызываться каждый раз, когда вы используете генератор:

     # Если слева от узла еще есть дочерний объект
     # И если расстояние в порядке, вернуть следующий объект 
     if self._leftchild and distance - max_dist < self._median:
        yield self._leftchild

     # Если справа все еще есть дочерний объект узла
     # И если расстояние в порядке, вернуть следующий объект 
     if self._rightchild and distance + max_dist >= self._median:
        yield self._rightchild 

     # Если функция попадает сюда, генератор будет считаться пустым
```

*вызов*:

```
# Создать пустой список и список с ссылкой на сам объект
result, candidates = list(), [self]

# Цикл по candidate(он содержат только один элемент в начале)
while candidates:


     # Получить последнего элемент candidate и удалить его из списка
     node = candidates.pop()

     # Получить расстояние между obj и candidate
     distance = node._get_dist(obj)

     # Если расстояние в порядке, вы можете заполнить результат
     if distance <= max_dist and distance >= min_dist:
        result.extend(node._values)
    

     candidates.extend(node._get_child_candidates(distance, min_dist, max_dist))

return result
```

Этот код содержит несколько логических частей:

- Цикл выполняет итерацию по списку, но список расширяется, пока цикл повторяется :-) Это краткий способ просмотреть все  данные, даже если это немного опасно, поскольку вы можете получить бесконечный цикл. В этом случае `candidates.extend (node._get_child_candidates (distance, min_dist, max_dist))` исчерпывают все значения генератора, но при этом продолжают создавать новые объекты генератора, которые будут давать значения, отличные от предыдущих, поскольку он не применяется к одному и тому же узлу.
- Метод `extend()` - это метод списка, который ожидает итерируемый объект и добавляет все значения в список.

Обычно мы передаем ему список:

```
>>> a = [1, 2]
>>> b = [3, 4]
>>> a.extend(b)
>>> print(а)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Но в вашем коде он получает генератор, это хорошо, потому что:

1. Вам не нужно читать значения дважды.
2. У вас может быть много объектов, и они не будут хранится в памяти.

И это работает, потому что Python не волнует, передаётся ли ему списком или нет. Python ожидает итерируемый объект, поэтому он будет работать со строками, списками, кортежами и генераторами! Это называется утиной типизацией и является одной из причин, по которой Python такой крутой. Но это уже совсем другая история...

<sub>Перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/231855/14227417) от участника [e-satis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9951/e-satis)</sub>